# Java Server & C# Client freezing

Tags: java, c#, server, client

I have got a Java Server and a C# Client. And I'm really certain something goes wrong with the outputstreamer on the client or inputstream on the server.

```
byte[] arr = IOUtils.toByteArray(is,14);
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(os, true);
out.print("Received "+ new String(arr,"UTF-8"));
out.flush();
out.close();
```

"is" in this case is the Input Stream Variable. Coming from Socket.getInputStream(). 
Removing the length of the stream (14 in this case) makes the system time-out. The client does not get any respons except: "Read Failure"

The client side consists of a C# program

```
 byte[] start = getIdentifier();
 byte[] end = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(toSend);
 byte[] arr = start.Concat(end).ToArray();
 //Arr variable is a couple of strings smashed together and transformed into a byte[]

 networkStream.Write(arr, 0, arr.Length);
 networkStream.Flush();
 StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(networkStream);
 result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
```

I actually tried writing to the Server with a BinaryWriter too, but that didn't work either. If I know what the length of the data is that will be send, I can fix the problem. But I do not know how to send the length of the stream to the server.

I've tried using Available() to see how much there was to read, but for some reason that sometimes was 0. As if the data wasn't been sent by the client yet.

Any ideas of how to fix the freezing?

EDIT:

I think I understand how the streaming works now. 
At first I did this on the client side:

```
var length = BitConverter.GetBytes(arr.Length);
Array.Reverse(length);
```

Then on the server side I put this piece of code:

```
 /* Get Input Data Length */
 byte[] arr = IOUtils.toByteArray(is, 4);
 int length = (arr[0] << 24) & 0xff000000 |
              (arr[1] << 16) & 0x00ff0000 |
              (arr[2] << 8) & 0x0000ff00 |
              (arr[3] << 0) & 0x000000ff;

 /* Get Input Data */
 arr = IOUtils.toByteArray(is, length);
```

@Andreas your mention of the big-endian byte order made it clear how to send the length to the server

Comment: A network stream will not signal end-of-data until you close the stream, so of course `IOUtils.toByteArray(is)` (without length parameter) will wait forever for end-of-data. Since network streams may chop data anywhere, a `read()` on the stream may give you only partial data, so you need to keep reading until you get all the data. How do you expect server to know when all the data has been received? You don't send an end-of-request marker, and you don't send the request size, and request is not fixed-size, so how would server ever know when all data has been received? Send string length first.

Comment: What Andreas said, and also the same on the client side: ReadToEnd() will read until the end of the stream, i.e. until the connection has been closed.

Comment: Sending the string length would mean I have to stream to the server an extra time? But depending on the size of what has to be send, it is not possible to know the exact length of the string length. So that would bring me to the exact same issue. Or do I not get that right?

Comment: @peter What do you mean you don't know the exact length? You're sending `arr.Length` bytes. That's the exact length and you know it. Just send data length as a 2-byte (`short`) or 4-byte (`int`) value first, using [big-endian byte order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness).